# Цикл по связанным объектам

Tags: java, java-hashmap

Имеется объект типа Entry со своими полями где хранятся ключ (Long) и значение (String) и ссылка на следующий объект этого же типа. Эти объекты в свою очередь находятся в массиве (Entry[] table), в общем реализация аналогичная HashMap. Верно ли реализован метод получения ключа по значению? Как бы вы его сами реализовали?

```
public Long getKey(String value) {
    if(value == null){
        return 0L;
    }
    for (Entry table : table) {
        for (Entry e = table; e != null; e = e.next)
            if (value.equals(e.value))
                return e.getKey();
    }
    return null;
}
```

UPD, вот код класса возможно будет понятнее:

```
public class MyCustomHashMap implements MyInterface {
static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;
static final float DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75f;
Entry[] table = new Entry[DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY];
int size;
int threshold = (int) (DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY * DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR);
float loadFactor = DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR;

int hash(Long key) {
    return key.hashCode();
}

int indexFor(int hash, int length) {
    return hash & (length - 1);
}

Entry getEntry(Long key) {
    int hash = (key == null) ? 0 : hash(key);
    for (Entry entry = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)]; entry != null; entry = entry.next) {
        Long k;
        if (entry.hash == hash && ((k = entry.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            return entry;
    }
    return null;
}

void resize(int newCapacity) {
    Entry[] newTable = new Entry[newCapacity];
    transfer(newTable);
    table = newTable;
    threshold = (int) (newCapacity * loadFactor);
}

void transfer(Entry[] newTable) {
    Entry[] src = table;
    int newCapacity = newTable.length;
    for (int j = 0; j < src.length; j++) {
        Entry e = src[j];
        if (e != null) {
            src[j] = null;
            do {
                Entry next = e.next;
                int i = indexFor(e.hash, newCapacity);
                e.next = newTable[i];
                newTable[i] = e;
                e = next;
            } while (e != null);
        }
    }
}

void addEntry(int hash, Long key, String value, int bucketIndex) {
    Entry e = table[bucketIndex];
    table[bucketIndex] = new Entry(hash, key, value, e);
    if (size++ >= threshold) {
        resize(2 * table.length);
    }
}

void createEntry(int hash, Long key, String value, int bucketIndex) {
    Entry e = table[bucketIndex];
    table[bucketIndex] = new Entry(hash, key, value, e);
    size++;
}
```

}

Comment: все компилируется

Comment: >>реализация аналогичная HashMap<< что то на хешмап ваш пример не походит... покажите хотя бы одну строчку где бы вы использовали ваш хеш для адресации?

Comment: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java - смотрите метод getNode, вот там действительно хешмап, без всяких ваших вложенных циклов с заоблочной сложностью алгоритма

Comment: делаю почти как в 7 jdk, добавил почти полный код класса

Comment: @Regent >>не могут названия переменных совпадать<< могут, разные области видимости. Меня смущает первый цикл.... который не играет роли... ради чего он тут?

Comment: @test123 насчет "заоблачной сложности" - метод `getKey` тут ищет ключ, связанное значение которого совпадает с заданным значением.. Нестандартная такая штука для Map.

Comment: @Reject а, да, у вас же `table` - это поле, пардон. Тогда это просто из серии "не надо так делать". То есть код писали не вы, если вас смущает цикл?

Comment: как бы немного модифицированный HashMap чтобы можно было по значению искать ключ.

Comment: Неужели нет двустороннего HashMap-а? Зачем велосипедить его?? И уберите первый цикл.

Comment: @Reject внешний `table` - это массив `Entry`, набор корзин. Внутренний `table` - это уже связка из `Entry`, лежащих в одной корзине. В результате чтобы пройтись по всем имеющимся `Entry`, нужно в каждой корзине пройтись по всей цепочке (связке) - итого два цикла.

Comment: @Regent код писал не я, но немного его доработал, изначально он возвращал не e.getKey() а table.getKey()

Comment: Короче, по мне, велосипед вида for(String key : data.keySet()) { if (data.get(key).equals(findValue)) return key; } return null; - и то логичнее чем это...

Comment: @test123 чем вам не угодил первый цикл? Если говорить об имеющемся решении, а не о "всё переделайте".

Comment: @Regent, сглупил я, нету тут yield return. Да и не очевидно всё, ради такого метода копипастить весь хешмап...

Comment: Объясню код: в массиве лежат объекты которые могут ссылаться на другие объекты, этакий односвязанный "LinkedList" в каждой ячейке массива

Comment: @test123 ну это в учебных целях только)

Comment: Нечто такое https://pastebin.com/rJwUSMEv , кажется проще, хотя, может у вас ещё какие подводные камни есть...

Comment: В общем написал пару проверочный тестов, данный код выполняет свою задачу правильно, всем спасибо за обсуждения.